# website takes 40 to 60 seconds to load page

Tags: php, mysql, database, magento

I am using magento for creating the ecommerce site.Currently i installed magento to viewdeal.com/emtheme (subfolder).This path takes too much time to load webpage and sometime it shows database errors.Admin page also having these problems.How to rectify the problem.

But in localhost it works fine.After i copy the project to live server the problem arises.

Also the main domain(viewdeal.com) having another magneto theme installed it tooks normal to load the webpage but viewdeal.com/emtheme loads very slow.

I think its database problem but not sure, i'm using cpanel how to restart or stop mysql service.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: i think the problem may be two magento installation on single domain in different folders

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem in this link http://localhost/emtheme/skin/frontend/default/em0119/images/loading.gif remove or replace this with another,http://viewdeal.com/emtheme/skin/frontend/base/default/js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.js is also not loading try to put it at the end of your php file.Dont use these fancy sliders because it takes time to render do replace with small responsive slider.

- Also your images are not optimized,do optimize them

Answer (score 0):

I would guess you have it in a debug mode or similar, it is the initial connection that takes the longest, thou all the js files do there part as well. Below was the debug from me trying to connect, maybe it might help you work out a solution.

[image]